# Google Drive SDK, Document Reader

Tags: ms-word, document, xmlreader, phpword

Is there anyway that I can use google docs api to process my document without having to upload the document to google server?

Or is there any library or documentation on how to get the details from a word file please share it, i would really appreciate any help thank you.

Comment: "Is there anyway that I can use google docs api to process my document without having to upload the document to google server?" - No

Comment: I guess i had figured out that answer by myself anyway thank you for confirming though :(

Answer (score 0):

I have found few documents and spent hours of time and finally found a solution to convert docx file in html format, now i know why there exist on paid service to convert files from docx to html or it might be any other format. anyway thanks,